# Redirect to subdomain if specific subdirectory found in URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect this (old blog domain)

**https://website.com**/post/182464294751/post-title

To a subdomain while keeping the rest of the url/subdir

**https://tumblr.website.com**/post/182464294751/post-title

I need to have a redirect /post/ is found on the url

Comment: Do the “old blog domain” and “new subdomain” point to different places? Is `/post` a physical subdirectory? Is the “old blog domain” being used for anything? What other directives do you have in the .htaccess file at the “old blog domain”? What have you tried so far? And in what happens?